# How can I add values to a column that show the ranking by a random value?

Tags: t-sql

I can't see what is going wrong here:

```
DECLARE @cData TABLE(cID NVARCHAR(1), cSeed DECIMAL(8,8), cRank INT)

INSERT INTO @cData (cID, cSeed) SELECT 'W', RAND()
INSERT INTO @cData (cID, cSeed) SELECT 'X', RAND()
INSERT INTO @cData (cID, cSeed) SELECT 'Y', RAND()
INSERT INTO @cData (cID, cSeed) SELECT 'Z', RAND()

SELECT cID, cSeed, (RANK() OVER (ORDER BY cSeed)) AS cRank FROM @cData 

UPDATE @cData
    SET cRank = (SELECT (RANK() OVER (ORDER BY cSeed)))

SELECT * FROM @cData
```

Why am I getting different results from my first select statement than I am from my second--why didn't my update statement put the same data into the table that my first select statement displayed?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> SELECT (RANK() OVER (ORDER BY cSeed))
> ```

This is a statement on its own, correlated by a column used only in `OVER / ORDER BY` clause.

It operates over an implied rowset of exactly one record (the current record from @cData) and hence always returns 1, as the rank of the only record in a set is 1 by definition.

I believe you want to run this instead:

```
WITH    t AS
        (
        SELECT  *,
                RANK() OVER (ORDER BY cSeed) rnk
        FROM    @cData
        )
UPDATE  t
SET     cRank = rnk
```

Comment: This is a really good example where a CTE as target for an UPDATE can be a really good idea!

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks.